# A question about complex mappings

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading the book "Complex Variables and Applications" by Brown and Churchill.

I'm confused about complex mappings. Say we have $f(x+i y)=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$.

I'm given to understand that if the mapping is represented in the form $f(z)=w$, then $x+iy$ is mapped in the $z$-plane, and $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ in the $w$-plane. Moreover, in the $z$-plane, $y$ is expressed as a function of $x$ ($y=g(x)$), and in the $w$-plane $v(x,y)=h(u(x,y))$.

How is it obvious that $v(x,y)$ can be expressed as a function of $u(x,y)$?

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't, unless we're considering an implicit map sort of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general, $y$ need not be a function of $x,$ nor does $v$ need to be a function of $u.$ $u$ and $v$ are both functions of $x$ and $y$, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Given a mapping $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$, we can project onto the real and imaginary parts to get $u,v:\Bbb C\to \Bbb R$. Viewing $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$, we can further refine $u,v$ to be functions with real variables $x,y$ into $\Bbb R$. This has all been done in your answer so far.

Conversely, any two functions of two real variables $g,h:\Bbb R\times \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ define a mapping $g(x,y)+i\cdot h(x,y):\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$. These two mappings are completely independent of each other in general: you can pick them at will!

You may run into certain applications where additional conditions force a link between the two. You haven't given any indication that this is the case, though.